# Cannot install docker version 17.03.2 from Ubuntu Bionic 18.04 server?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

Current version I have is 18.06.0-ce.

I followed the instructions at the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce-1) to install a specific version.

This command is supposed to list all the versions available.

```
apt-cache madison docker-ce
```

But it only displays the 18.~ versions.

```
docker-ce | 18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/edge amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.05.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/edge amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/edge amd64 Packages
 docker-ce | 18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu | https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic/stable amd64 Packages
```

So unable to do this.

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=<VERSION>
```

How do I install the version I need.

The reason I want this specific version is because [Rancher docs](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/single-node-install/) state they are the only compatible versions.

[image]

Comment: docker only has packages for 18.03+ for bionic.  It's likely that rancher will work fine with a _newer_ version of docker -- have you tried that?

Comment: The listed versions from the quoted documentation are no longer supported. CE releases are supported for roughly a month after the following CE release. Try the current CE release instead.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the contained copied from official docker guide. Please read the Note: and try to find the repository that you want to use. Below repository is pointing to the latest version.

Use the following command to set up the stable repository.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
```

**Note: Starting with Docker 17.06, stable releases are also pushed to the edge and test repositories.**

Answer (score 0):

```
 $ sudo snap install docker
```

This gives docker 17.06.02-ce which is the oldest build I found for Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You can download docker by following command. I have tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial
```

Answer (score 0):

As the docker documents

> If your cannot use Docker’s repository to install Docker CE, you can
>   download the .deb file for your release and install it manually. You
>   need to download a new file each time you want to upgrade Docker CE.

Your can use the scripts blew.

```
# docker-ce depends on libltdl7 (>= 2.4.6)
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libt/libtool/libltdl7_2.4.6-6_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libltdl7_2.4.6-6_amd64.deb

wget https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/xenial/pool/stable/amd64/docker-ce_17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i docker-ce_17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial_amd64.deb
```